# StackPanel and the .NET 4 Client Profile

Tags: wpf, user-controls, stackpanel, .net-client-profile

I have an old WinForms app that needs a few new forms, which would benefit greatly from WPF.  Following this tutorial:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms

The project currently targets the .NET 4 Client Profile.

I added a WPF control.  However, when I drop a StackPanel into the control in the designer, the designer displays the following error message:

> Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.

Changing the target to the full .NET 4 resolves the issue.  However, requiring the full .NET 4 library for a client app seems to defeat the purpose of having a client profile.

Is there a way to accomplish what I want and still target the client profile?

Comment: You can't drag a WPF into a WinForm Control. You need to put an ElementHost first.. and then you put the WPF element into this control

Comment: I am using an ElementHost as described in the tutorial I reference in my post.